# Android make layout darker to emphasize another part

Tags: android, background

I want to create a loading animation in a card view in the middle of the screen, and I want to emphasize the card view, so I want to make everything a bit darker except for the card view. How can I make my layout a bit darker?

**In the image you can see how I want my background**

[image: Here the background is dark as I wish]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say it's the right way to do it but that's how I'm achieving it.

I do this by making a view with background grey (#808080) and alpha 0~0.9 (alpha controls the transparency of a view), I would show this view (visible) when I need to darken things and hide it (Gone) when I finish.

to control its appearing above all other view I use elevation attribute (programmatically called TranslationZ I think) with high enough value to appear above all other views but not as high as what I actually want to show in front of the screen.

a simple example from one of my codes to do this where I wanted a single image to appear above a RecycleView when click, I would set the whole child constraint-layout to visible when I needed to show the image and invisible/Gone when I'm not:

my layout xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycle_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:elevation="2dp">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/maximized_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <View
            android:id="@+id/shade"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:background="#808080"
            android:alpha="0.9"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image_basic_label"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:elevation="4dp"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and when I need to show in code I'd just do this :

```
     maximizedContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

where `maximizedContainer` is the child constraint-layout